# This seems strange

Tags: cipher, steganography

Yesterday, after physics, I looked into my history book and found this strange note:

> **IMPORTANT SECRET MESSAGE**
>   Dtzw Htruzyjw mfx gjjs jshwduyji. Knsi tzy ymj htwwjhy pjd. F qnyyqj mnsy: nrlzw ity htr xqfxm LRVfn

After I solved the riddle, I felt a bit angry because the message was promoting a website but it was a StackExchange website so everything was ok for me

Can you Find oUt What the name oF the stAckexchange website is? (Tip: you might need imgur)

Comment: Wait... why would you look into your history book after physic? That seems suspicious....

Comment: @North i am a student and they are school books. And hints

Comment: in the first image rot13()Gur gvzr qvivqrq ol gur qbyynef tvirf gur ebg xrl jvgu n yvggyr punatr.

Comment: @AlanHoover yes, but the only way to get there is to have already solved that part :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From @North & @WELZ answers,
if you put link :

> HvsQcffsqhGczihwcbWgEiobhiaQcadihwbuGhoqySlqvobus

and

> using ROT12

you get :

> THECORRECTSOLUTIONISQUANTUMCOMPUTINGSTACKEXCHANGE

and add space, the **ANSWER** is :

> THE CORRECT SOLUTION IS QUANTUM COMPUTING STACKEXCHANGE

This is my first answer. Sorry if any wrong format, bad english or other mistakes.

Comment: My intended solution was: 1. find out that there is an imgur with the capital leters from the last sentence 2. go to my profile page, click on the Get it in a blue moon (=impossible) question, divide the qid by six, the modulo 26 is 5, 26 - 5=21. This is the intended rot. 3. decrypt the message and go to the page. Take the time (20:56:22) and concat them, modulo 26 gives 14, the 26-14=12, the rot required to decrypt the final message.

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't thought as far as go to your profile. I've tried all method I know with the time (20:56:22) and ended with 14. With 9781 too. And the missing "d" at address look curious. Thanks, I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 4):

#### Partial answer:

If you take the:

> Capital letters from your last sentence (minus the first one C): `FUWFA` which can be converted to an imgur link by messing with the case `https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUwFa.png` 
>  Which brings up: 
> [image]

Using @North's answer you get:

> Imgur link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMQai.png

Which brings up:

> [image]
>  `HvsQcffsqhGczihwcbWgEiobhiaQcadihwbuGhoqySlqvobus`

And if you:

> Take the Capital letters from the address you get :`HQGWEQGS`

Comment: I am sorry but this is not the right direction. Maybe there is some other hint in the image allowing you to decrypt the adress. And you also don't explain correctly **why** you can decrypt it via rot21.

Comment: Ummm why do we exactly have to answer *why*? Any decipherer can crack that even without a computer by simply brute-forcing it. Also the fact that F stands by itself makes it obvious that F=A or F=I. Using F=A, you can simply decode it very easily. Seems to be an unnecessary step to me to try and explain Why a rot21 works (maybe because it decodes it?)

Comment: @North but there is an hint inside the question and your solution is not complete if you can't explain why it is correct. Hint: the capitalized characters in the last sentence (except C) give you a new imgur link that will allow you to find out what you need to do (by the way *history* is a hint too)

Comment: @North you got the right picture. What has something to do with SE and history and impossible...

Answer (score 3):

By decrypting it using rot21 you get:

> "Your Computer has been encrypted. Find out the correct key. A little hint: imgur dot com slash GMQai."
>
> This was easily deciphered by finding out that f=a, working backwards from there. Find the opposite of rot6, decrypts it.
>  Thanks to @Welz, the second imgur picture gives you the rot # it was encrypted to --> "You'll only get sixth... if F=A, that uses a rot6 cipher.

Comment: yes, but it does not contain the hint the last sentence gives and you have not explained why rot21 and what the answer to my question is.

Comment: Fudge I can't go to the imgur website, its blocked for me.

Comment: this still does not explain why this decryption is correct in the context of the riddle (tip: look at the last sentence)

Comment: Updated the answer @MEE

Comment: oh There is an shortcut. The sixth on the picture was originally something different 